# Continuous curves and diameter of a set

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose I have a sequence of compact Riemannian manifold $(M, g_{i})$, and I know that for any $p, q$ on $M$, and any $i$ there exists a continuous curve $\gamma_i$ on $(M, g_{i})$ starting at $p$ and ending at $q$, with arc length $L$. Is it possible to conclude that the diameter of $M$ with respect to $g_i$ is uniformly bounded by $L$?

Thoughts:
The curves are just continuous, but my guess is that one can always approximate it by a smooth curve whose length is $\varepsilon$ close to it for any metric. Then maybe one can conclude that the diameter of $(M, g_i)$ is uniformly bounded by slightly enlarge $L$.

Comment: Just a thought: Is it possible to hammer out a contradiction to Stone-Weierstrass from the assumption $d(p,q) \geq L + \varepsilon$?

Comment: It is a bit unclear  for me. $L$ is a given constant?

Comment: If $L$ is independent of $i$, then the fact of a sequence appears to be a red herring. So, is the question actually: "Assume for $p$, $q$ in $M$, there is a continuous path $\gamma:[0,1] \to M$ from $p$ to $q$, and the supremum of $\sum_{i} d(\gamma(t_{i-1}), \gamma(t_{i}))$ over all finite subdivisions of $[0, 1]$ is equal to $L$ (and $d$ is the length of a minimizing geodesic). Then there exists a geodesic from $p$ to $q$ of length $\leq L$"?